# Is there an Esperanto publisher that I could buy books from?

Tags: culture, literature

I have found a few authors writing in Esperanto. I'd like there to be more of that in the future. I have found quite a few things for free on the internet. Instead of that, I'd like to know that when I pay for something there'll be more literature in the future. Is there a publisher, for example, that someone could recommend?

Comment: Support by buying their books/works or by means of donations or personal help?

Comment: You should use wooden beams.

Comment: Lyubomir, in a way that there will be more authors in the future and so that authors currently working can continue their work.

Comment: What is your budget? Are you thinking about 5-10 dollars per month?

Comment: Tony, I was thinking of the system in general, like where do you buy books where it actually supports the authors, for example. Because I'd like to buy my books from a place where the authors receive the money.... I'm not sure how the industry works, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't understand why this is on hold. There is a clear answer to this question, there is a finite amount of publishers and book shops, like UEA, FEL, Impeto, Literatura Foiro, Esperanto-USA etc.

Comment: Ah I see it now, the edit that doesn't make it too broad any more has just been made 1 hour ago...

Comment: Maybe I can roll back the edit somehow and ask a new question instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of bookshops and publishers from which you can order Esperanto books. Given that sending costs can depend on how far you live from the location of the bookshop of publisher, I will always mention which country they operate from.

The bookshop with the greatest choice of Esperanto books is certainly the [*Libroservo de UEA*](http://katalogo.uea.org/) in the Netherlands. Furthermore, many national Esperanto associations have there own bookshops: The [*Esperanto-Retbutiko*](https://www.esperanto.be/fel/gb/ls_serchu.php) by the Flamish Esperanto League (FEL) in Belgium has a special position among them, as it serves customers from all over the world, functions as an important publisher and probably has the second biggest choice of books after the *Libroservo de UEA*. Other noteworthy examples are the [Esperanto-USA Retbutiko](http://www.esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/) (USA), [*Libroservo de GEA*](http://www.esperanto-buchversand.de/) (Germany) and [EAB Bookshop](http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/bookcat.htm) (UK).

You can also order books directly from the publishers. UEA and FEL are important publishers themselves. Here is a list of other important publishers:

- [Mondial](http://www.librejo.com/) (USA)
- [Sezonoj](http://esperanto-ondo.ru/Ind-libr.htm) (Russia)
- [Impeto](http://impeto.trovu.com/) (Russia)
- [Espero](http://www.espero.sk/?akcia=zmenjazyk&jazyk=EO) (Slovakia)
- [E@I](http://www.ikso.net/eo/projektoj/eldonajxoj.php) (Slovakia)
- [KAVA-PECH](http://www.kava-pech.cz/) (Czechia)
- [Edistudio](http://www.edistudio.it/) (Italy)

If you want to follow what is happening in the Esperanto literature scene, you should subscribe to [Beletra Almanako](http://www.beletraalmanako.com/), a literary magazine published by Mondial (USA) that comes out three times a year in book format (you can also buy single issues).

Note that recently scams of Esperanto translations based on Google Translate (or some other not reliable machine translation) have appeared on Amazon. So don't buy an Esperanto book on Amazon without having seen that particular book or translation mentioned in a positive way on a serious Esperanto website.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is still unanswered, I'll make a start, and suggest the [Esperanto-Asocio de Britio's bookshop](http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/bookcat.htm).

This answer is a [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [link](http://www.esperanto-buchversand.de/) to the GEA's online bookstore.